# reset PATH variable OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, path

My $PATH look like this

```
echo $PATH
=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/gradle-2.14.1/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop-2.7.2/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/gradle-2.14.1/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/gradle-2.14.1/bin
```

As you can see, there's a `"="` symbol at the beginning, and I have no idea where it comes from, or how to get rid of if.

I also notice things are repeated twice.

Here's the content of my `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-2.14.1
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Here's the content of /etc/paths

```
cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

There's no ~.bashrc, there's no /etc/profile. There's nothing under /etc/paths.d.

Comment: Why not start by commenting out all those things in your bash_profile and see what happens?

Comment: There's something else involved, but I can't tell what from what you've described.  It looks like the commands in ~/.bash_profile are being run 3 times(!), with some other stuff between the first and second runs. Try adding `set -x` at the beginning of your ~/.bash_profile, so it prints each line as it executes it; then see what that reveals about what's going on.